# How can I change the title of the welcomepage programatically?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

The code below is not working. (no exceptions thrown). Totally clueless why is not changed When I check in the GUI, there is a new version, with no changes!

```
public static void SetEntityWebName(ProcessEntity entity, SPWeb entityWeb)
        {
            try
            {
                entityWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                var welcomePageListItem = entityWeb.GetFile(entityWeb.RootFolder.WelcomePage).Item;
                var welcomePage = entityWeb.GetFile(entityWeb.RootFolder.WelcomePage);
                welcomePage.CheckOut();
                if (entity.Type == Entity.Job)
                {
                    entityWeb.Title = ((SyncJobs_Result)entity.Entity).JobName;
                    welcomePageListItem["Title"] = ((SyncJobs_Result)entity.Entity).JobName;
                    welcomePage.Update();
                }
                if (entity.Type == Entity.Client)
                {
                    entityWeb.Title = ((SyncClients_Result)entity.Entity).ClientName;
                    welcomePageListItem["Title"] = ((SyncClients_Result)entity.Entity).ClientName;
                    welcomePage.Update();
                }
                if (entity.Type == Entity.Opportunity)
                {
                    entityWeb.Title = ((SyncOpportunities_Result)entity.Entity).OpportunityName;
                    welcomePageListItem["Title"] = ((SyncOpportunities_Result)entity.Entity).OpportunityName;
                    welcomePage.Update();
                }
                welcomePage.CheckIn(string.Empty);
                welcomePage.Publish(string.Empty);
                entityWeb.Update();

              }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              }
        }
```

Comment: do something in your `catch` block, see if there are any `Exceptions`

Comment: there are no exceptions, I am debugging the code line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you also have to update the welcomePageListItem  list item .

I am not sure but , give it a try